# Any software that can determine malware running on background?

Tags: malware, task-manager, tasks

I mean like task manager, but provides an information if the running process is malignant or not.

Comment: If it's truly malignant, it won't show up at all anywhere ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

clearly the 'mother' of all task managers: **[AnVir Task Manager](http://www.anvir.com/)** (even the free version beats the competition hands down).

the following features would be of particular interest to you:

> Security risk rating for each active
>   process, service and startup program.
>   The security risk rating indicates the
>   likelihood of a program being
>   potential virus, spyware, malware or
>   trojan. The rating is based on
>   behavior, code analysis, and
>   integrated database.
>
> Get notification when any program
>   tries to add itself to startup, and
>   cancel useless or harmful startup
>   program.
>
> Right click on any suspicious process
>   or file and check it on virustotal.com
>   with 30+ antiviruses.

Answer (score 2):

[Process explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) might help, though it's not specifically designed for that.

Answer (score 0):

That's called a Virus-Scanner, [AntiVir](http://www.free-av.com) f.e. .

Answer (score 0):

[Security Task Manager](http://www.neuber.com/taskmanager/index.html) may give you some guidance, but rarely certainty. No chance against rootkits though.

Real antivirus may be your best choice here.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) as previously mentioned, you can look up different processes on the [Process Library site](http://www.processlibrary.com/).  Note, though, that some malware/virus processes masquerade with the same names/inside common system processes.

I agree with AdamV that a real Antivirus/Antimalware software may be your most certain/safest route.

Answer (score 0):

There's also [Ad-Aware](http://www.lavasoft.com/).

It will report on malicious processes and registry entries.